# Else for multiple if's

Tags: c++

Is it possible to make multiple if's and one else for all of them without using the bool variable? I'm talking about something that works like this:

```
bool triggered = 0;

if (condition)
{
    //code
    triggered = 1;
}
if (condion2)
{
    //code
    triggered = 1;
}
if (!triggered)
{
    //code
}
```

So if none of these if's happened - something happens. In pseudo-code I would write it like this:

```
{
   if()
   {

   }
   if()
   {

   }
}
else
{

}
```

Is there a possibility to make something similar?

Comment: Don't assign integer values (`0` and `1`) to `bool`s - use `true` and `false` please. Recovering C programmer?

Comment: Nah, C++ was my first language. I just found it shorter way, nobody said me that it is bad practice before.

Comment: And you didn't think that using the wrong types and relying on type conversions might be .. sub-optimal ..? One of C++'s nice properties is type safety..

Comment: Well, i will keep it in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do it like that. You can do:

```
if (condition1 || condition2) {
    if (condition1) {
        //code
    }
    if (condition2) {
        //code
    }
} else {
    // code
}
```

But this means you have to test `condition1` and `condition2` twice. And if there are lots of conditions, the first `if` will be very long.

I find your code with the `triggered` variable preferable. Often, there's already a variable that serves the purpose. For instance, form validation code often looks something like this:

```
std::string errors;
if (field1 is invalid) {
    errors += "Field1 is invalid\n";
}
if (field2 is invalid) {
    errors += "Field 2 is invalid\n";
}
if (errors == "") {
    // process the form
} else {
    // display error message
}
```

Comment: So which of the ways would you say is more correct, readable, elegant? The one you shew me, or my from example?

Comment: @Smorts What do you think I meant when I wrote "I find your code with trigger variable preferable"?

Comment: Oh, I don't know how I could've missed it. Sorry, anyway, thanks for help :)

Comment: Another way is to create a function which returns true if the condition was successfully evaluated.